# Calculate total units sold and total sales value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

Can you help me check my answers whether is this the right way? Im really new to database

This is the question
[image]

This is my answer

```
Create View totalsales AS
select inv.InvoiceDate, po.ProdCode, po.ProdName, sum(il.Quantity), sum(il.SellingPrice)
from Invoice inv, Product po, InvoiceLine il
where inv.InvoiceNo = il.InvoiceNo and po.ProdCode = il.ProdCode and inv.InvoiceDate between ('01-01-2021','dd-mm-yyyy') AND ('31-03-2021','dd-mm-yyyy')
group by inv.InvoiceDate, po.ProdCode, po.ProdName, il.Quantity, il.SellingPrice
order by sum(il.Quantity) DESC
WITH READ ONLY CONSTRAINT totalsales;
```

The reason i use with read only constraint was to enhance the security!

Comment: Obviously you are learning SQL - use modern ANSI join syntax and don't get used to old, proprietary Oracle join syntax.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'm not sure it's Oracle proprietary syntax unless there's an `(+)`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, at least the `JOIN ... ON` syntax is more common than `... , ...`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I would certainly hope so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it, query would look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW totalsales AS
    SELECT
        po.prodcode,
        po.prodname,
        SUM(il.quantity) sum_quantity,
        SUM(il.sellingprice) sum_sellingprice
    FROM
             invoice inv
        JOIN invoiceline il ON il.invoiceno = inv.invoiceno
        JOIN product     po ON po.prodcode = il.prodcode
    WHERE
        inv.invoicedate BETWEEN DATE '2021-01-01' AND DATE '2021-03-31'
    GROUP BY
        po.prodcode,
        po.prodname
WITH READ ONLY;
```

If compared to yours:

- don't select columns you don't need (`invoicedate`) as it affects the final result because you then have to include it into the `group by` clause so you'd get values "split" per each invoice date as well (and that's not what you want)
- properly JOIN tables (i.e. don't include them in the `FROM` clause separated by a comma, and then don't *join* them in the `WHERE` clause - put conditions in there
- condition is related to invoice dates; your code is missing the `TO_DATE` function, e.g. `between to_date('01-01-2021','dd-mm-yyyy')`. In this case, I'd suggest you to use date literal which is always in format `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'`
- `with read only` *only*; nothing else
- sorting within a view? That doesn't make much sense (in my opinion). Just *create it*, and then sort values when you select from the view, e.g.

  ```
  select prodname, sum_quantity
  from totalsales
  order by sum_quantity desc
  ```

Comment: May i know why Join is used?

Comment: But @Littlefoot, if i insist of applying the sorting command will it be smtg like this "order by sum(il.Quantity) DESC" , i just meet the questions condition. TQSOMUCH

Comment: That would be `order by sum_quantity desc`. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

May be you consider to create view like this:

```
   Create View totalsales AS
    select po.ProdCode, po.ProdName, 
     sum(il.Quantity), sum(il.SellingPrice*il.Quantity)
    from Invoice inv, Product po, InvoiceLine il
    where po.ProdCode = il.ProdCode(+)  
     and il.InvoiceNo = inv.InvoiceNo(+)  
      and trunc(inv.InvoiceDate(+),'Q') = date'2021-01-01'
    group by po.ProdCode, po.ProdName
    order by sum(il.Quantity) DESC
    WITH READ ONLY
```

It shall output all products. But for products not been sold in 1st quarter of 2021, aggregates will be null. If you need only products been sold in 2021 - remove all **(+)** from predicates.

I also wrote **sum(il.SellingPrice*il.Quantity)**
for total sales, because I'm not sure that sellingPrice is a price for all the quantity, not just for one unit. If sellingprice is a price for all units, then just replace  **sum(il.SellingPrice*il.Quantity)** with
**sum(il.SellingPrice)**.

Comment: may i know what is the + sign used for?

Comment: That's "old" Oracle's outer join operator.

Comment: Why you call it "old"? It still used in latest Oracle versions. Moreover, you can't do certain things without it. For example to build materialized views with fast refresh.

Comment: And you can't do certain things with it, @Andrew (for example, outer join the same table to more than only one another table; unless I'm wrong, of course) . "Old" because it was used in versions prior to 9i, and that's *old*.

Comment: @Littlefoot, the situation above is not the case for outer join with more than one table. However, it is turn  of topic's author to say some words about  all answers, mentioned above.

Comment: We're just discussing the "old" adjective here, @Andrew. You asked why I called (+) so, and I responded. BTW, *materialized view with fast refresh* isn't case here either so we're just wasting each other's time.